# Set DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Value Based on a Datatable

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox, datagridviewcolumn

I read several article relating to setting the value of a combobox however I still couldn't come up with a solution.

Below is a basic example of what I want to do and in the comments is exactly what I want to do. Any help is appreciated.

```
  Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("ID")
    dt.Columns.Add("Name")
    dt.Columns.Add("Value")
    dt.Columns(0).AutoIncrement = True

    For i As Integer = 0 To 20
        Dim R As DataRow = dt.NewRow
        R("Name") = "Test" & Date.Now & "" & i
        If i = 2 Or i = 5 Or i = 6 Or i = 8 Or i = 10 Then
            R("Value") = "yes"
        Else
            R("Value") = "no"
        End If
        dt.Rows.Add(R)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    Next

    DataGridView1.ReadOnly = False

    Dim cmb As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
    cmb.HeaderText = "Select Data"
    cmb.Name = "cmb"
    cmb.MaxDropDownItems = 2
    cmb.Items.Add("True")
    cmb.Items.Add("False")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(cmb)

    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        If dr("Name").ToString = "Test" Then
            'set the combo box value to True
        Else
            'set the combobox value to False
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `cmb.SelectedItem = "True"` (or "False"). However, you might consider using a checkbox instead, checked for True, unchecked for False...

Comment: Selecteditem is not a member of DataGridViewColumn box - True and False is a concept. Could be Red Blue yellow as the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `value` by setting the `Cells.Value`...

```
 DataGridView1.Rows(whatrowdoyouwant).Cells("cmb").Value = True
```

On another note, you set the `DataSource` to the `DataGridView`, but loop through the `DataTable`. If you want to set each row in the `DataGridView` this wont work.

```
 For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
    If dr("Name").ToString = "Test" Then
        'set the combo box value to True
    Else
        'set the combobox value to False
    End If
 Next
```

You would need to loop through each `DataGridViewRow` in the `DataGridView` and set the `ComboBox` value. For example...

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    If DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Name").Value.ToString = "Test" Then
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("cmb").Value = True 
    Else
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("cmb").Value = False
    End If
 Next
```

Comment: yep you are correct. I figured that out a bit ago that I would have to loop through the datagridview rather than the datatable. then set the cell value to what ever.

Comment: Glad to be of help!